# Blender 2.8. Trying to join bezier curve with bezier curve made from spiral: "Cannot make segment" error

Tags: modeling

I created a spiral curve with the spiral curve tool. Then, I added a curve modifier to the spiral curve to make it follow a path. I applied the modifier and deleted the object curve so that the spiral curve remained following the modified path as seen in the image attached.

I am attempting to join the spiral curve to another curve. The first curve is a bezier curve. In Edit mode, I selected the end point of each curve and hit "F" to connect the curves. I got the "Cannot make segement" error.

In edit mode, just to be sure, I went into Curve> Set Spline Type for the spiral curve to bezier. I got the same error.

In the attached image showing the properties window for the objects, you can see that spiral curve is named Spiral.194 under the "num" column in the property chart. It's data type is listed as "Spiral.005". The other curve is named "DNA_Twist.001" and it's data type is listed as "BezierCurve.000.

I'm wondering if, even though I converted the spline type of the spiral curve to bezier, if it won't join the curves because the data types are different? I'm very new to Blender, so any help would be very much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to join 2 curves in Blender. You could convert them both to mesh, join them, and convert back to curves.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. In Edit mode, I went to Segments> Switch Direction. I switched directions of the first curve. Then I selected the all of the vertexes in both curves and hit "P". The first couple of times I tried, it joined the wrong ends of the curve segments together. After each failed try, I switched direction of one curve or the other. On my fourth of fifth try, it joined the curves together into one segment.

Comment: Correction: actually, I meant I hit "F", not "P" as stated above. Sorry. And to clarify, before any of the above, in Object mode, I joined the curves together using CTRL-J.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things I've found that make a "Cannot make segment" error.

1. The control points you are joining aren't compatible.
   Set the handle type for the control points that are to be connected to *Vector.*
   [Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/editing/control_points.html#set-handle-type)
2. The spline types aren't the same.
   Toggle Edit Mode and *Curve ‣ Set Spline Type ‣ Bezier.*
   [Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/modeling/curves/editing/curve.html?highlight=spline%20type#set-spline-type)
3. The curves haven't been joined.
   Select both curves and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
   [Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/join.html)

Comment: Welcome to BSE and great first answer! Could you possibly reword or further explain "aren't compatible" from case no. 1?

Answer (score 0):

Set handle type for the control points, only the ones to be connected, to *Vector*.

Then with both of the points to segment selected press  <kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

when you try to press 'f' to make a loop.you need to make sure that those two line should be composite into one object.otherwise you won't successfully make that loop